# Probability that two random matrices span the full matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ drawn at random in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, what is the probability that the matrix algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ is the full matrix algebra $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

That is, if $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of matrices defined by

- $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ and
- $XY\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $X,Y\in\mathcal{A}$,

what is the probability that $\mathcal{A}$ contains $n^2$ linearly independent matrices?

I have the intuition that this should occur with probability one, but I can't manage to prove it. If that helps, using Burnside's theorem I think that this is equivalent to the fact that there are no common invariant subspaces for all matrices in $\mathcal{A}$ except for $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: With what distribution do we select matrices?

Comment: If your equivalent condition is correct, then it suffices to note that both $A$ and $B$ will have $n$ distinct eigenvalues and no common eigenvectors with probability $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnomn I guess it does not really matter which distribution we generate the random with, as long as its distribution is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ does it? Maybe my question would be better phrased using Lebesgue measure as "does the set of matrices $A,B$ for which $\mathcal{A}$ has dimension strictly less than $n^2$ have Lebesgue measure 0?"

Comment: Well, you would need a distribution which is "absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure".  But yes, we sidestep all that if we just talk about Lebesgue measure directly, which has the right intuitive meaning.

Comment: @Omnomnomnomn I think the fact that both $A$ and $B$ will have distinct eigenvectors is not enough: what if $x,y$ (resp. $x',y'$) are eigenvectors of $A$ (resp. $B$) and the spaces spanned by $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x',y'\}$ are equal? (and the same for any subset of m<n eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$...)

Comment: Okay, I see where this gets a bit complicated... interesting

Comment: Does this mean "can we always find a linear combination of monomials in A and B to construct any matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: @mathreader Yes (with probability one..)

Answer (score 2):

1. An algebra $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies: $XY,X+Y,\lambda X\in \mathcal{A}$.
2. The Burnside's theorem gives a NS condition when the underlying field $K$ is algebraically closed. In particular, it is false over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, if you study real matrices, you must consider theirs COMPLEX common invariant subspaces.

EDIT 1. I wrote too fast (because Lemma 2 is valid only if $A,B\in M_n(K)$ where $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(i)$).

We consider a discrete distribution of probability over $\mathbb{Q}$ s.t., for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $P(\{q\})>0$.

Here $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is the COMPLEX subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $A,B$.

Lemma 1. Let $U=[u_{ij}]\in M_n$ where the $(u_{ij})$ are commuting indeterminates and $K=\mathbb{Q}((a_{ij}))$. Then $\chi_U$, the characteristic polynomial of $U$, is irreducible over $K$ and, $Galois(U)$,  its Galois group over $K$ is $S_n$.

Proof. Let $P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that has degree $n$ and $S_n$ as Galois group (such a polynomial exists for every $n$). We specialize $U$ into $U_0$ so that $U_0$ is the companion matrix of $P$. Then $Galois(U_0)$ is a subgroup of $Galois(U)$ and, consequently, $Galois(U)=S_n$.

Assume that the $(u_{ij})$ are randomly chosen in $\mathbb{Z}\cap [-\delta,\delta]$; according to the Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, $Prob(Galois(U)\not= S_n)\approx O(1/\sqrt{\delta})$. Thus, if the $(u_{ij})$ are chosen in $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Prob(Galois(U)\not= S_n)=0$.

Lemma 2. If $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, $AB\not= BA$ and $Galois(A)=S_n$, then $A,B$ admit no common invariant proper subspaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

Proof. cf. Theorem 3, in my paper (published in linear and multilinear algebra):  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3630.pdf

Proposition 1. If $A,B$ are randomly chosen in $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, then $Prob(\mathcal{A}\not= M_n(\mathbb{C}))=0$.

Proof. Randomly choose $A$ ($A$ has a.s. $n$ distinct eigenvalues; then, a.s. $dim(C(A))=n$). Use Lemma 1. (a.s. $Galois(A)=S_n$). Randomly choose $B$. Then, a.s. $B\notin C(A)$. Use Lemma 2. and Burnside's theorem.

Remark. If you use the "RandomMatrix" of maple (for example) for $U$, then the $(u_{ij})$ are random integers that are between $-100$ and $100$; $Prob(Galois(U)\not= S_n)$ is very low (in fact much smaller than the bound specified by Hilbert Theorem) but is not $0$.

EDIT 2. Since the moderator is unhappy about our discussion, I give the following proof.

Proposition 2. Assume that the entries of $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are iid random variables that follow the normal law. Then $Prob(\mathcal{A}\not= M_n(\mathbb{C}))=0$.

Proof. According to the answer-comment below, it suffices to prove that: let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be fixed with $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then the set of $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that has distinct eigenvalues and an eigenvector in a proper invariant subspace of A has Lebesgue-measure $0$.

We may assume that $A=diag((a_i))$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}=(e_i)$. Then a proper invariant subspace of $A$ is included in $span(\mathcal{B}\setminus e_j)$ for some $j$. Then it suffices to prove that $Z=\{B|B\;\text{has }\; n\; \text{eigenvalues and has an eigenvector }\;u\in span(\mathcal{B}\setminus e_n)\}$ is negligible in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Put $B=\begin{pmatrix}B_{n-1}&c\\l&b\end{pmatrix},u=[v,0]^T$ where $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\setminus 0$. If $Bu=\lambda u$, then $B_{n-1}v=\lambda v$; thus the polynomials $p(x)=\det(B-xI_n)$ and $q(x)=\det(B_{n-1}-xI_{n-1})$ have a common root, that implies that their resultant $result(p,q)$ is $0$. Note that $result(p,q)$ is a polynomial in the $(b_{ij})$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, that $Z\subset \{B|result(p,q)=0\}$ and consequently, that $Z$ is Zariski-closed. It remains to prove that $result(p,q)$ is not identically $0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider $B_n=J_n+J_n^T$ where $J_n$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $n$. Then $spectrum(B_n)=\{2\cos(\dfrac{j\pi}{n+1}),j=1,\cdots,n\}$ has no common entries with $spectrum(B_{n-1})$ and $result(p,q)\not=0$ for $B_n$

Comment: Thanks for clarifications 1. and 2., I edited my answer to take 2. into account. I must confess that I am not familiar enough with algebraic geometry and Galois theory to really understand your proof. Do you think there may be a simpler way to prove this result? Does the one I tried in my answer makes sense to you?

Comment: Does your remark (at the end of your answer) imply that the proof I proposed is false?

Comment: No, my remark is not linked to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a proof... I am not sure that it is very rigorous (especialy for the last paragraph), so any comments are welcome.

I will try to show that the set of couple of matrices having a (non-trivial) common invariant subspace has Lebesgue measure 0. Using Burnside's theorem this is equivalent to the fact that the set of couple of matrices $(A,B)$ for which the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ has dimension strictly less than $n^2$ has Lebesgue measure 0.

Let 
$\mathcal{S} = \{(A,B)\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \times  \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \ | \ \exists U\subsetneq \mathbb{C}^n, U\not = \{0\} : Au\in U \text{ and } Bu\in U \text{ for all } u \in U\}$.

Given a matrix $A$, let $\mathcal{S}(A) = \{B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \ | \ (A,B)\in \mathcal{S}\}$.

For any set $X$, let $\mathbb{I}[X]$ denotes the indicator function of the set $X$.

Finally, for any integer $k$ let $\mathcal{M}_k$ bet the set of $n\times n$ matrices with Frobenius norm less than $k$. We will use the notations  $\mathcal{S}_k = \mathcal{S}\cap \mathcal{M}_k$ and $\mathcal{S}(A)_k = \mathcal{S}(A) \cap \mathcal{M}_k$.

Using Fubini's theorem for the Lebesgue measure (which is positive), we have
for any integer $k$
$$\int_{(A,B)} \mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}_k]=\int_{(A,B)\in\mathcal{M}_k\times \mathcal{M}_k}\mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}] = \int_{A\in\mathcal{M}_k}\int_{B\in\mathcal{M}_k}\mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}(A)_k] .$$

Thus if we show that $ \int_{B\in\mathcal{M}_k}\mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}(A)_k] = 0$ for any matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_k$, this will imply that $\int \mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}_k]=0$. Using the monotone convergence theorem we will have

$$ \int \mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}] = \int \lim_{k\to \infty} \mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}_k] = \lim_{k\to\infty} \int \mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}_k] =\lim_{k\to\infty} 0 = 0$$
hence showing that the set $\mathcal{S}$ has Lebesgue measure 0.

<s>It remains to show that $\mathcal{S}(A)$ has Lebesgue measure 0 for any matrix $A$, which will imply $\int_{B\in\mathcal{M}_k}\mathbb{I}[\mathcal{S}(A)_k] = 0$ for any integer $k$. Let $A$ be a matrix and let $V_1,\cdots,V_p\subsetneq \mathbb{C}^n$ be its non-trivial invariant subspaces. Now let $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Since the set of non-diagonalizable matrices has measure 0 in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, we assume that $B$ is diagonalizable. Then, a necessary condition for $B\in\mathcal{S}(A)$ is that there exists an eigenvector of $B$ that lies in one of the $V_i$. Since $\bigcup_i V_i$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, it follows that $\mathcal{S}(A)$ also has measure 0.</s>

It remains to show that for a generic matrix $A$, $\mathcal{S}(A)$ has Lebesgue measure 0...

Comment: I read quickly your post. I note at least $2$ mistakes: 1. "$S(A)$ has Lebesgue-measure $0$ for any matrix $A$" is false (if  $A=I_n$, then $S(A)=M_n$). 2. "If $B\in S(A)$ is diagonalizable, then an eigenvector of $B$ is in some $V_i$" is false.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes 1. is clearly false... I guess I should try to show that the set of matrices A for which S(A) has non-zero Lebesgue measure is of measure 0? For 2. if $B$ is diagonalizable any invariant subspace of B is the span of some of its eigenvectors $x_1,\cdots,x_k$, then $B\in S(A)$ implies $span(x_1,\cdots,x_k)=V_i$ for some $i$ thus $x_1,\cdots,x_k\in V_i$. What is wrong with this reasonning?

Comment: Of course 2. is true. Yet, $A$ may have a non-countable set of non-trivial invariant subspaces. More precisely,  $A$ has a finite set of invariant subspaces iff $A$ is cyclic.

Comment: Moreover, in "Since $\bigcup_i V_i$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, it follows that $\mathcal{S}(A)$ also has measure 0.", you admit the only implication to prove !

Comment: Regarding 2. By cyclic matrix do you mean circulant matrix? I thought that a matrix with distinct eigenvalues of multiplicity one has a finite number of invariant subspaces (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152137/counting-invariant-subspaces-of-a-vector-space). Is it true that a generic matrix have a finite number of invariant subspaces? Your comment suggests that it's not.

Comment: No, $A$ is cyclic iff there is $x$ s.t. $x,Ax,\cdots,A^{n-1}x$ is a basis ($A$ is similar to a companion matrix), that is equivalent to: $A$  is non-derogatory. In particular, if $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then it is cyclic. Moreover, a generic matrix has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok. So it seems that there should be an easy way to prove the result: if we draw $A$ at random, $A$ has distinct eigenvalues  with probability one. Hence a.s. $A$ has a finite number of proper invariant subspaces $V_1,\cdots,V_k$ and $\cup_i V_i$ has measure 0 in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Now if we draw $B$ at random, a.s. it has distinct eigenvalues and the probability that an eigenvector of $B$ is in  one of the $V_i$ is 0. Hence $A$ and $B$ does not share a common invariant subspace and the algebra they generate is $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, $A$ is fixed with $n$ distinct eigenvalues and $B$ is not. You must PROVE that the set of $B$ that has (complex) distinct eigenvalues and an (complex) eigenvector in  an invariant subspace of $A$ is negligible. -it is not obvious- For example, do you know how to prove that the set of matrices with multiple eigenvalues is negligible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a proof that does not rely on Burnside's theorem. Any comments are welcome.

**Theorem.** For any couple of matrices $(A,B)\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, let $P(A,B) = \{A^iB^j : 0\leq i,j <n\}$. Then the set $S = \{(A,B) : P(A,B) \text{ is not a basis of } \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

**Proof.** For any couple of matrices $(A,B)$ let $M(A,B) \in \mathbb{C}^{n^2\times n^2}$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectorizations of $A^iB^j$ for $0\leq i,j<n$. Then $(A,B)\in S$ if and only if $det(M(A,B)) = 0$. Since $det(M(A,B))$ is a polynomial in the coefficents of $A$ and $B$, $S$ is an algebraic subvariety of $(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})^2$. We now show that the polynomial $det(M(A,B))$ is not $0$. Let $U$ be the upper $n\times n$ shift matrix, we claim that $det(M(U,U^\top))\not = 0$, which is equivalent to $P(U,U^\top)$ being a basis of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Let $(E_{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, one can check that $E_{ij} = U^{n-i}(U^\top)^{n-j}- U^{n-i+1}(U^\top)^{n-j+1}$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$ (note that  $U^{n-i+1}(U^\top)^{n-j+1}$ is either in $P(U,U^\top)$ or equal to $0$). In conclusion, $S$ is a proper algebraic subvariety of $(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})^2$, thus of Lebesgue measure zero.