# Burnside's theorem on invariant subpaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

One version of this theorem states that if $E$ is a complex vector space with $\dim(E)<\infty$, and $A$ an unitary sub-algebra of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ for which there are no non-trivial subspaces $F$ invariant by all the elements of $A$ (simultaneously), then $A=\mathcal{L}(E)$. In other words, if $A$ is a strict unitary subalgebra of $\mathcal{L}(E)$, then there is a subspace $F$ non-trivial invariant by all elements of A.

Do you know some simple examples of such $A$ ? Could we prove some results concerning simultaneous triangularization using directly this theorem?
I have only found other theorems resulting of this one, or examples not very simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two examples.

i) Two randomly chosen complex $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ span the full matrix algebra with probability $1$. cf. my post in

[Probability that two random matrices span the full matrix algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806940/probability-that-two-random-matrices-span-the-full-matrix-algebra/1808294#1808294)

Note that it's not obvious...

ii) -Easier- Let $A,B$ be two $2\times 2$ matrices s.t. $e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}\not= e^Be^A$. Show that $A,B$ are simultaneously triangularizable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The use on this website is that if you are satisfied by an answer, then you accept it, that is to say, you give it the green chevron.

Comment: Thanks. cf. also my post in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265499/showing-the-existence-of-invariant-2-dimensional-subspaces-for-some-certain-en/3265863#3265863